# Fixed width font with better substitution for Greek/Hebrew/Chinese

Tags: terminal, font

Some of my filenames are in Hebrew, Greek, or Chinese.  In Terminal, the font substitution for Hebrew in every fixed-width font I tried was unsatisfactory.  Either the Hebrew characters were smaller and fainter, or the horizontal spacing was extremely bad.  Changing the font size in Terminal apparently has no effect—changing font face or style instantly affects the shell window, but changing the size from 12 to 18 did nothing.

**Is there a font I can install that will result in a better substitution with Menlo or some other MacOS fixed-width font?** . I prefer sans-serif, but readability (which demands fixed-width) is more important.  And hopefully fixing the Hebrew won't screwup the Greek and Chinese!